# About number of benches and students

Tags: logic

In a class there are some benches and students.
If each student sit in one bench,one student is left out.If two students sit in one bench ,one bench is left out.Find number of students and benches.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be the number of students and $b$ the number of benches.

You get that $s = b+1$ and $s = 2(b-1) = 2b -2$

Thus $2b-2 = b+1$ ie $b=3$ and $s=4$.

Or $s = b+1$ and $s = 2(b-1)-1 = 2b -3$ if you allow one of the bench to have one student when placing two students per bench.

Thus $b+1= 2b-3$ ie $b=4$ and $s=5$